# Different css stylesheets from redirectiong

Tags: css

I have a welcome page, which have two buttons- "full" version and simplified. Both will redirect to same page, but depending on which button was "main" page entered through I want to load different CSS file (simplified version will only have background colors, not images). How can it be done? (I'd preffer javascript, html and css).

Comment: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Attach a parameter to the url: `yoururl.com/main.html?full=0`
2. Get the parameter with JS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8463056/2587420
3. Load the specific CSS with JS: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml