# NoReverseMatch js variables in django url

Tags: javascript, django, templates, url, d3.js

I'm trying to pass js variables in a django {% url %}, but with no success.
I built a D3 bar chart, and i would like to link each bar to a different page, rendered by django. The pages are working well, and when i push the static data (all bars to the same page) it works well. How should i add js variables?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460265/get-a-variable-from-url-parameter-using-javascript)?

Comment: I'm trying to do the opposite: put a js variable value in a django template url tag {% url 'some_page' js_variable %}

Comment: Then [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591525/is-it-possible-to-pass-query-parameters-via-djangos-url-template-tag) should help.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm trying to pass it in the {% url 'some_page' js_variable %}

Answer (score 1):

You can't: the results of the `{% url %}` tag are compiled on the server side but the javascript is run on the client side.

You could use an AJAX endpoint to provide the function of the `{% url %}` tag.  Create a view which runs `reverse()` and returns the result in a JSON response.  You could then pass your parameters to it and do something with the result using Javascript.  A VERY simplistic example:

urls.py

```
url(r'^posts/(?P<pk>\d+)$', 'app.views.post', name='post_view'),
url(r'^url$', 'app.views.url_endpoint_view', name='url_endpoint')
```

views.py

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse

def url_endpoint_view(request):
    name = request.GET.pop('name')
    data = {'url': reverse(name, kwargs=request.GET)}
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

Template:

```
<a href="#" id="post_link">Dynamic link to a post</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
$.get('/url?name=post_view&pk=5', function(data) {
    $('#dynamic_link').attr('href', data.url)
});
```

Comment: Thanks! quite disappointing to acknowledge that. I solved it by using a list of JS if statements.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I found replace could work on this. Here is my example code:

```js
const html = matches.map(match => 
`<a href="{% url 'case' 9999 %}"class="btn btn-primary btn-block">More Info</a>`.replace(/9999/,match.pk)).join('');
```

I summarized the code to prevent flood but you could guess what this part does. It first puts /case/9999 for every match, but then it replaces 9999 with the id in primary key, so it's converted to /case/1, /case/3, etc...

If you have the possibility to have 9999 as id, you could change it to anything you want of course.