# Pull variable from a URL and set it as value of textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following URL: `http://localhost:8888/datatest?username=JD042719`
I want to pull in the `"JD042719"`. 
This problem does not require a 'Get' request. 
Then the username value should be set to the value of another text box. Perhaps something like this:

**HTML**

```
<label for="Assoc">Associate ID</label>
<input type="text" name="AssocID" id="AssocID" required="required">
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function associd(){
document.getElementById("AssocID").value=username;
});
```

Comment: take a look into javascripts HTTP GET functions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### New answer (2021)

The answer below is quite outdated. Unless you need to support Internet Explorer, you should just use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) as follows:

```js
var username = (new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)).get("username");
```

### Old answer (2015)

Use the excellent function provided in **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/3307872)**, like so:

**Usage**

```js
var username = getParameterByName("username");
```

**Function**

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

The variable `username` should now hold the value `JD042719` (or whatever value is in the URL).

Comment: So im trying this and I get this error. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Comment: @JordanDavis Sorry for the late reply. The usage is with quotation marks: `getParameterByName("username");`. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, that probably saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
 var url = window.location.href.split(/[=]/);
```

Then you could reference

```
 url[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Javascript does not have fun built in ways to get to get these url variables. Some languages do such as PHP. So in javascript we have to be more creative. 
Here is a function that you can call to get a variable value if you know the name of the variable.

```
function GetUrlVar (varName) {
  varName = RegExp ('[?&]' + name.replace (/([[\]])/, '\\$1') + '=([^&#]*)');
  return (window.location.href.match (varName) || ['', ''])[1];
}
```

So now in your case you would call this function and pass in username like so

```
document.getElementById("AssocID").value=GetUrlVar('username');
```

EDIT: I looked back and I used this from a previous question so I wanted to give credit where it is due. [Get a variable from url parameter using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460265/get-a-variable-from-url-parameter-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Something quick and easy....

Use `.split()` to break down the url and look for the `username` parameter.

```
var theUrl = "http://localhost:8888/datatest?username=JD042719";
var args = theUrl.split("?");

for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {

    if (args[i].indexOf("username") > -1) {
        alert(args[i]); //output: username=JD042719
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

location.search will provide you string after and with ?query="SEARCH" . Now do split and take out the term. These the simplest method·

Answer (score -1):

you must use `$_GET` to do this "it's PHP not JS"

```
<?php $username=$_GET['username'];?>
<label for="Assoc">Associate ID</label>
<input type="text" name="AssocID" id="AssocID" required="required">
$(function associd(){
document.getElementById("AssocID").value=<?php echo $username; ?>
});
```

Comment: There's no indication of OP being able/willing to use PHP whatsoever, so why suggest PHP?